# The Linux timeout command and exit codes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout

In a Linux shell script I would like to use the **timeout** command to end another command if some time limit is reached. In general:

```
timeout -s SIGTERM 100 command
```

But I also want that my shell script exits when the command is failing for some reason. If the command is failing early enough, the time limit will not be reached, and timeout will exit with exit code 0. Thus the error cannot be trapped with **trap** or **set -e**, as least I have tried it and it did not work. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your situation isn't very clear because you haven't included your code in the post.

`timeout` does exit with the exit code of the command if it finishes before the timeout value.

For example:

```
timeout 5 ls -l non_existent_file
# outputs ERROR: ls: cannot access non_existent_file: No such file or directory
echo $?
# outputs 2 (which is the exit code of ls)
```

---

From `man timeout`:

> If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then
>   exit with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.  If
>   no signal is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM
>   signal kills any process that does not block or catch    that signal. 
>   It may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal
>   cannot be caught, in which case the exit status is 128+9 rather than
>   124.

---

See [BashFAQ105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) to understand the pitfalls of `set -e`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I have indeed overseen this part of the manual. I will investigate your hint with the pitfalls regarding set -e.